# "Can't shift that many" error in dash case statement

Tags: linux, scripting, sh

I am running Arch Linux and scripting in Dash.

I have a dummy script that outputs all the variables I set using parameters. I followed a tutorial that recommended getting input this way. [Link to article](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-shell-script-in-linux/)

```
while [ ! -z "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        --param|-p)
            shift
            #code
            ;;
        --other-param|-op)
            shift
            # code
            ;;
    esac
shift
done
```

In the MRE below, entering the `-e` parameter produces the error "shift: can't shift that many" on the `shift` line inside that parameter's code. It is consistent and I don't have any clue what it means.

***Why is this error being thrown?***

My MRE script is running dash as the shell and is as follows.

```
#!/bin/dash

while [ ! -z "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -e)
            shift
            echo "Error right about..."
            ;;
    esac
shift
done
```

Output of `./mre.sh -e`

```
Error right about...
./mre.sh: 32: shift: can't shift that many
```

Comment: When you start a script with arguments (e.g. `./script A B "C D"` the three arguments `"A"`, `"B"` and `"C D"` are called *positional parameters*. `$1` access the first positional parameter, `$2` the second and so on... When you need to loop over all positional parameters or take them in sequence, you use `$1` and then call `shift` which removes that positional parameter moving the next into its place for processing (e.g. `shift` makes `$2` the new `$1`) That way you can process all positional parameters until there are none left to process.

Comment: When you have processed an option, you remove it from the list of arguments. That's what the `shift` does. If you don't remove the option you just processed, you will process it again and again in an infinite loop. I suspect the error comes from the second shift after `esac` but this is too messy to spend more time on.

Comment: Compared to so many Qs here, your's looks well presented. Actually it is too long, as others have identified.. There are a couple of people that seem to get of on downvoting without commenting. Don't worry about it. Keep posting Qs like that, and you'll get all the help you need. Maybe you got downvoted for using `dash` ;-) . ... if you're going to continue using `arch` on a "regular" sized computer, please switch to using `bash`.  Thanks DavidRankin, you explained the O.P.s Q perfectly! Good luck to all.

Comment: (See my slight edit above). Also, I find the [mcve] to be very "high-level" and not that helpul for a new user. I recommend to work your way thru [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section of `tags/bash/info`. (And check out the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section in the same link). Good luck.

Comment: Yes through further research I have learned what shift is, and I still don't get why I get the error. I will make a MRE. I do know what those are but I just thought that the example near the top would be considered as the MRE. It is the same structure I used in my script so that's why I included it. See roughly line 18 and that code. I will try and make a full MRE and update the post if it still errors out. Also what's wrong with dash? I'm new to Linux but I heard that bash is not POSIX compliant and less compatible and slower. That's not true?

Comment: Hey I made an MRE! Updating now please check out the new question @shellter tripleee DavidC.Rankin

Comment: @tripleee I have added an MRE and can reliably reproduce the error. Could you please check out the updated post? Also I am not new to stack overflow but I am not good at posting so thank you for the links. I read the MRE one. I also shortened the question

Comment: Well like I wrote above, you can't `shift` twice when there is only one argument. (And that's not an MRE because thereeare many lines inside the `case` which are unnecessary for reproducing.)

Comment: @tripleee well I tried my best okay? Anyway you just helped me figure it out. That was exactly the issue, but you worded it differently this time which helped me understand. At this point I am just going to put an actual MRE (hopefully) and move on. If you want to post an answer I'll check it.

Comment: agree that this is still not a perfect MCRE, but so much better than before. So pluse-uno from me. Again, please read the [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section of `tags/bash/info`? and especially the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section ain the same link. When you start paring down your problem a 1-2 lines of code, or even 1-2 pipe separated commands, you often find the answer yourself, rather than having to wait and play 20 Qs with readers here ;-). Glad you got a solution. Good luck to all.

Comment: As far as `dash` vs `bash` and POSIX compliance. It's possible to write POSIX compliant scripts using `bash`. It all depends on your use-case in scripting. If your employer or a contract mandates POSIX, then stick to that standard. If you don't need to write scripts with one hand tied behind your back, then use the advanced features that `bash` provides. ALSO if the error you posted at the top, "Can't switch that many" is really indicating too many switch/case targets, yikes, any good software now has no realistic limits on anything, let alone that (IMHO!). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `shift` after `esac`.  You have already processed all the arguments in `"$@"` in your demo, so there is nothing left to shift.

The tutorial you are following attempts to demonstrate how an option *with an argument* like `-t 12` leaves the argument in `$1` after the first shift, and then shifts that off too when it's done with it. (I would not do things this way; the second shift should happen inside the `case` when you are done with that particular option, so that you don't force *all* your options to require an argument.)

Bash would work exactly like Dash in this respect, though it doesn't give you an explicit error message when it can't `shift` any more.